# Register values from 0x20000000 to 0x20000FFC

Tags: c, microcontroller

I want to read the values of the register starting from 0x20000000 to 0x20000FFC.

Architecture: ARM
Register width: 32 bit

I did following:

```
#define REG      0x20000000

unsigned int volatile * const port = (unsigned int *) REG;

for(int i=0; i<4093; i++)
{
    printf("%d", *(port+i));
}
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: You probably want the bounds of the `for` loop to be `for(int i=0; i < 0x1000 / sizeof(int); i++)`.

Comment: If `int` is 32 bits on your platform, it's probably correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define REG      0x20000000

unsigned int volatile const* port = (unsigned int *) REG;

for(; port < (unsigned int *) REG+0x1000; port++)
    printf("%u", *port);
```

Comment: I guess I have to remove the const, otherwise it's not modifiable, right?

Comment: no, you modify the pointer, not the lvalue it is pointing to, which is constant.

Comment: but somehow I get a error saying that  
"expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Comment: @OcK It is pointer to `constant volatile int`, yes, I edited the form.